# how to call jQuery in admin as well as in homepage

Tags: plugins, admin, jquery

I have this jquery code inside my wordpress admin page that checks if the input value is empty.

```
$j(function(){
$j('form').submit(function(){

     var link = $j('#input').val();
    if(link == ''){
         alert('hi there');
    }

});

});
```

Now if the form is empty it will alert ' hi there'.

the plugin works fine but the alert does not show on the main page. Only in the admin section.

what would be the problem?

here is how I am calling jquery.

```
function test(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'js/test.js');


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','test');
add_action('admin_head','test');
```

I would like that if the value of input is empty, the alert show also in the wordpress homepage and not only in the admin page.

Comment: The first bit of javascript is where exactly? In your test.js file?

Comment: yes Wyck thats test.js

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(){
    wp_enqueue_script('myscript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'js/test.js',array('jquery'));
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts','test');
add_action('wp_head','test');
```

Comment: added that, but same thing Gembel. the alert only shows at the admin page.

Comment: hmm.. not sure why. is your js appear when you view page source? just in case you forget to add wp_head(); in your template :D

Comment: yes it does appear Gembel.

Comment: how about testing your js in jsbin?

here is my test http://jsbin.com/omumit/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is that you are enquequeing jquery.

You don't need to do that, as WordPress does it by default. Just remove

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: that will never work. this is a plugin and I am calling jquery.

Comment: But you do not need to call jQuery!

Trust me, I have recently submited plugin to WordPress.org and before approving it, I needed to remove jQuery call. 

There is no need for calling jQuery with plugins!

Comment: ok well... gave that a shot too.. no changes.

Comment: What does your browser console say?